# Property Assignment vs Variable Assignment: What is the standard?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

Referring to [this article](http://www.bryanbraun.com/2014/11/27/every-possible-way-to-define-a-javascript-function) by Bryan Braun about different ways to define a Javascript function, I have a question about standards.

Say you have multiple objects and want to give each a member `name` with the value `"Programmer"`, what is the more proper or standard way to go about setting this in Javascript if you MUST use a function to get the information?

Variable Assignment? For example:

```
var GetName = function() {
       return {"name": "Programmer"};
}

var newObj = GetName();
```

or Property Assignment? For Example:

```
var obj1 = {
  GetName: function() {
    obj2.name = "Programmer";
  },

  GetObj: function() {
    return obj2;
  }
}

obj1.GetName();
newObj = obj1.GetObj();
```

or is there another way to call a function that would match this functionality that is even more proper, or the common standard for Javascript? I'm new to Javascript all together and learning all the ropes.

The previous, Variable Assignment, seems to be cleaner, and simpler. But Property Assignment seems more "put together", maybe secure. Though, I think there isn't much security when it comes to Javascript objects and functions.

So what is the standard for this type of functionality?

Comment: Your second example would produce a syntax error.

Comment: @MikeC thanks! I believe you are referring to the lack of a comma, and I edited to add it. If  you are reffering to the `obj2` var I didn't add that since this is more or less a code snippet.

Comment: No, I'm referring to the fact that you have functions without a function keyword or parameter list. `GetObj: { return obj2; }` should be `GetObj: function() { return obj2; }` or with the method syntax `GetObj() { return obj2; }`.

Comment: @MikeC Oh right! Thanks, missed that. Editing now for the fix!

Comment: I Can't understand what's your question exactly.

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you should create a simple function/constructor and initialize objects with that.

```
function GetName(){
    this.name = "Programmer";
}
```

and use it like

```
var obj1 = new GetName();
var obj2 = new GetName();
var obj3 = new GetName();
```

In javascript, functions are hoisted at the top, for function declaration is better than function expression.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding the usage-situations between Function Declaration and Function Expression. When would you use the previous vs the ladder?